# Does Gazebo limit FPS and can I turn it off?

Tags: gazebo-11

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

My simple simulation runs at around 62 FPS. I tried adding a lot of additional models and geometry in order to reduce the FPS, but the simulation still runs around the same framerate. That makes me think that my hardware is capable of running the simulation at a higher framerate, but Gazebo limits it to ~60 FPS. Is that the case, and can I turn the limit off?

I want to perform some performance experiments, so I need to see the direct impact of additional geometry and rigid bodies on the simulation performance.

**Gazebo Version:** 11.10.2
**CPU:** Intel Core i5-8250U
**GPU:** Intel UHD Graphics 620 (integrated)
**RAM:** 32 GB

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/28815/does-gazebo-limit-fps-and-can-i-turn-it-off?/) by [Envilon](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/148978/envilon/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2023-02-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

[image]

If you mean the `FPS` shown at the bottom right corner of the GUI, then it can be changed from the `World->GUI->camera->render rate` on the left panel. It can be set higher or lower. Note that this is not really related to the camera's frame rate, and with multiple and/or high resolution GPU sensors (cameras and GPU lidars), usually the FPS for the sensors will be much less in a complex world.

---

Originally posted by [Veerachart](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/39778/veerachart/) with karma: 226 on 2023-03-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Envilon](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/148978/envilon/) on 2023-03-02**:
Thanks for the answer, this looks like what I was looking for. It should be okay to use it as a performance metric, right? Since a more complex scene will result in a lower FPS of this main camera.

**Comment by [Veerachart](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/39778/veerachart/) on 2023-03-03**:
This GUI FPS is mainly affected by the number and details of the "Visual"s in the world, and not really by the GPU sensors in the world. If you are interested in the camera or GPU lidar's frame rate, then check their rates directly, not this FPS. This is capped by sensor's `<update_rate>`. Or if you are more interested in physics complexity, then it's the real time factor. In `Physics->real time update rate`, set to 0, and the simulation will be run as fast as possible. Higher RTF = faster sim.

**Comment by [Envilon](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/148978/envilon/) on 2023-03-03**:
Sorry, I am not familiar with GPU sensors in this context. What do you mean by GPU sensors?

RTF seems like a good metric for Gazebo performance tests. However, I want to compare Gazebo with other simulators (mainly the use of the Unity game engine), so the RTF might not be directly comparable to any of their metrics.

**Comment by [Veerachart](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/39778/veerachart/) on 2023-03-03**:
GPU sensors = Cameras and GPU lidars. They use GPU to simulate the sensor data.
If you are comparing with other simulators, there are more parameters to check, such as the solver the physics engine uses, and the time step of the physics update.